# Bind Rserve() to IP address on Windows

Tags: windows, ip, bind, listen, rserve

A colleague in our IT department is trying to install Rserve() in a WINDOWS environment.

The Rserve() instance does respond to localhost requests (127.0.0.1).

However, it is not binding to the machine's external IP address.  So it is not possible to call upon it from external machines.

Is there something special which needs to be done to troubleshoot or bind Rserve() to a specific IP address on WINDOWS ?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, we've moved away from running Rserve() on Windows.

Comment: It's not the answer to question!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!  The **rserv.cfg** file had been created in Windoze using `Right-Click --> New --> Text File`.

In Windows Explorer, it was displaying as **rserv.cfg**.  But actually, seen from a `DIR` command in the DOS prompt, the name of the file was **rserv.cfg.txt**

Since `remote disable` is the default, only setting `remote enable` in the **rserv.cfg** would fix the problem.  And the config file wasn't being recognized because of the incorrect .txt file extension.

Comment: The above steps solved the problem, but now `Rserve()` on Windows is broken again with the same problem: when killing the existing `Rserve` process & starting a new one the new process will not bind to the external IP address (only 127.0.0.1).  To get here, we have added a variety of `eval library("<package_name>");` lines into the **Rserv.cfg** in order to have those packages load automatically.  Now, even after removing those lines from **Rserv.cfg** and going back to the original, `Rserve()` will only listen on 127.0.0.1

Comment: The working directory of the rserve.exe process must contain the rserv.cfg file.